# Async await with sqs receive messages not working properly

Tags: python, asynchronous, boto3, python-asyncio

I am very new to async programming,I have a sqs channel from where i have to read messages but in between i have to bring my webserver up and perform the same receive message task later as soon the webserver is up.

Running the below program keeps on reading the sqs messages only, call never goes to webserver function. How can i make the following case work:

```
import boto3
import json
import logging
import asyncio
from aiohttp import web
app = web.Application()

max_queue_messages = 10
AWS_REGION='***'
AWS_KEY='***'
AWS_SECRET='***'

sqs = boto3.client('sqs', region_name=AWS_REGION,
        aws_access_key_id=AWS_KEY,
        aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET)


queue_url = 'queuename'


async def start_queue():
    while True:
        response = sqs.receive_message(
            QueueUrl=queue_url,
            AttributeNames=[
                'SentTimestamp'
            ],
            MaxNumberOfMessages=1,
            MessageAttributeNames=[
                'All'
            ],
            VisibilityTimeout=0,
            WaitTimeSeconds=0
        )
        if 'Messages' in response:
            try:
                message = response['Messages']
                payload_dict = {}
                payload_dict['payload'] = message[0]['Body']
                print("mesage from queue:")
            except Exception as e:
                logging.error(f'[sqs] error no message in queue -> {e}')
        else:
            time.sleep()
    return payload_dict

async def webserver():
    print("Starting web Server")
    web.run_app(app,host= "127.0.0.1",port= 5000)


async def func1():

    await start_queue()
    await webserver()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(func1())
```

Comment: Did you debug it to check "response" and know if your IF "Messages" in r... works?. Also your time.sleep() on else should not be on else, I suggest to do it always not only on else

Comment: I checked all the messages are coming fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You are running poll_queue directly as a coroutine. Execute it with the ensure_future(), it will wrap up the coroutine in a Task object. Only Task objects can be awaited and suspended by the event loop.

```
import aiobotocore
import json
import logging
import asyncio
from aiohttp import web
app = web.Application()

max_queue_messages = 10
AWS_REGION=
AWS_KEY=
AWS_SECRET=

queue_url =

async def poll_queue(client):
    while True:
        try:
            # This loop wont spin really fast as there is
            # essentially a sleep in the receieve_message call
            response = await client.receive_message(
                QueueUrl=queue_url,
                WaitTimeSeconds=2,
            )

            if 'Messages' in response:
                for msg in response['Messages']:
                    # print('Got msg "{0}"'.format(msg['Body']))
                    print('got queue message')
            else:
                print('No messages in queue')
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break

    print('Finished')
    await client.close()


def func1():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    session = aiobotocore.get_session(loop=loop)
    client = session.create_client('sqs', region_name=AWS_REGION,
                               aws_access_key_id=AWS_KEY,
                               aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET)
    asyncio.ensure_future(poll_queue(client))

async def hello(request):
    return web.Response(text="Hello, world")

def func2():
    app.add_routes([web.get('/', hello)])
    print("Starting web Server")
    web.run_app(app, host= "127.0.0.1",port= 5000)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    func1()
    func2()

    loop.run_forever()
```